# Enabling Wordpress Events Plus Plugin shortcodes in custom template

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I've recently purchased the events plus Wordpress plugin from http://wpeventsplus.com/ and am trying to get the calendar to show up on a template page. However, the shortcode [PLUS_CALENDAR] is not working on the template page I wrote. Here's my entire code for that page:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: page-registration
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        //
        // Post Content here
        //
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

My background is in HTML and CSS, and I'm not familiar with php much at all. I should also mention that my site is WP Theme converted from a normal HTML site, making it a little harder to work with plugins, as the code was not converted in a very clean way to php. I'm guessing I have a mistake, or a few, in my code, but I have no idea where to start looking, I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: where you tried to use the shortcode?

Comment: Your custom template is not flexible enough for adding more functions without advanced programming knowledge. Maybe, it would be a good choice to download a free template of your taste, which will mostly probable support adding plugins on the page layout.

Comment: Does you shortcode work when you add it to the body of a Post?

Comment: Thanks, @alariva, that's what I was thinking, unfortunately.

Comment: @PaulH The shortcode does not work when I add it to the body of a post.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a shortcode in a WordPress PHP file this way:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[PLUS_CALENDAR]'); ?>
```

Details: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

So your code becomes:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: page-registration
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        //
        // Post Content here
        echo do_shortcode('[PLUS_CALENDAR]');
        //
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: This seems to just places the text "[PLUS_CALENDAR]" into the webpage.